# Accidentaly deleted shared dropbox file on laptop!

Tags: dropbox, mac

HELP, I accidentally deleted loads of files on my mac on finder then emptied my recycle bin.. I had been shared into the folders on dropbox containing these files and am super worried that others who are also shared into these folders may have the same files deleted! They are not important to me but are to others!I was not the original person to share these folders.

Answer (score 4):

The [Dropbox web interface](http://www.dropbox.com) has a 'show deleted files' button (icon a small trash can) at the top of each folder view. Navigate to the folder which used to contain your deleted files (if you have deleted all your files, the home directory), click this icon and select 'restore' to restore your files.

See Dropbox's *[How do I recover deleted files?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/296/en)*.

Answer (score 1):

The files may not be compleatly deleted from the dropbox at all.

> It stores deleted files under the `Dropbox/.dropbox.cash/` directory (on MacOS and Linux, and I guess something similar on Windows) for at least 3 days. So you can either browse this directory and find your deleted files or simply restore the deleted files from the Web UI and then files that are in the cache will be moved to the original directory.

If it was deleted you should try one of the programs talked about on http://www.cultofmac.com/67472/how-to-undelete-files-in-mac-os-x-macrx/ Then take the recovered files and put them back in the dropbox folder.